# Error: Invariant Violation: Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.(…)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Reactjsで画像のBase64表現をサーバから取得し表示するコンポーネントを作成しています。コードは以下のとおりです。

**DataImage.react.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DataImageStore from '../../stores/DataImageStore';
import DataImageActions from '../../actions/DataImageActions';

export class DataImage extends Component{
  static propTypes = {
    path: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = this.getDataImageState();
    this.onStateChanged = this.onStateChanged.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    DataImageActions.fetchImage(this.props.path);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    DataImageStore.addChangeListener(this.onStateChanged);
  }

  componentDidUnMount(){
    DataImageStore.removeListener(this.onStateChanged);
  }

  getDataImageState(){
    return {
      image: DataImageStore.getImage()
    }
  }

  onStateChanged(){
    this.setState(this.getDataImageState());
  }

  render(){
    return <img src={this.state.image}/>
  }
}
```

**DataImageStore.js**

```
import AppDispatcher from '../dispatcher/AppDispatcher';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
import DataImageConstants from '../constants/DataImageConstants';

class DataImageStore extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(){
    super();
    AppDispatcher.register(this.onAction.bind(this));
    this.CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';
    this.image = "";
  }

  onAction(action){
    switch(action.actionType){
      case DataImageConstants.DATA_IMAGE_RECEIVED:
        this.image = action.image;
        this.emitChange();
        break;
      default:
    }
  }

  getImage(){
    return this.image;
  }

  emitChange(){
    this.emit(this.CHANGE_EVENT);
  }

  addChangeListener(callback){
    this.on(this.CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }

  removeListener(callback){
    this.removeChangeListener(this.CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }
}

let store = new DataImageStore();
export default store;
```

**DataImageActions.js**

```
import AppDispatcher from '../dispatcher/AppDispatcher';
import DataImageConstants from '../constants/DataImageConstants';
import DataImageUtils from '../utils/DataImageUtils';

export default {
  fetchImage: (path) => {
    AppDispatcher.dispatch({
      actionType: DataImageConstants.DATA_IMAGE_FETCH
    });
    DataImageUtils.fetch(path);
  },

  receiveImage: (image) => {
    AppDispatcher.dispatch({
      actionType: DataImageConstants.DATA_IMAGE_RECEIVED,
      image: image
    });
  }
}
```

**DataImageConstants.js**

```
import keyMirror from 'keymirror';

export default keyMirror({
  DATA_IMAGE_FETCH: null,
  DATA_IMAGE_RECEIVED: null
});
```

**DataImageUtils.js**

```
import request from 'superagent';
import DataImageActions from '../actions/DataImageActions';

export default {
  fetch: (path) => {
    request
      .get('/image/')
      .query({
        path: path
      })
    .end((err, res) => {
      if(err) return console.error(err);
      DataImageActions.receiveImage(res.text);
    });
  }
}
```

しかし、このクラスの親コンポーネントでpathを取得しViewを更新するとタイトルのようなエラーが出ます。どのように修正すれば上のエラーを解決できるのでしょうか。教えて下さい。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import request from 'superagent';

export class DataImage extends Component{
  static propTypes = {
    path: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      image: ""
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    request
      .get('/image/')
      .query({
        path: this.props.path
      })
    .end((err, res) => {
      if(err) return console.error(err);
      this.setState({
        image: res.text
      });
    });
  }

  render(){
    return <img src={this.state.image}/>
  }
}
```